# Payout start date, payout end date and payout date is incorrect

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get payout start date, payout end date and payout date from current date and time in Indian standard time (IST). If today is 22nd march in IST timezone then , my payout start date to be 17 March , payout end date to be 23 march and payout date to be 29 March. I wrote a function to get this done. But it gives me incorrect dates
my payout date comes as 22nd Mar, payout start date as 10 march, payout end date as 16 march

```
  dayIndex = 5;
  function nextDate(dayIndex) {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setDate(
      today.getDate() +
        ((dayIndex -
          1 -
          today.getDay() +
          7) %
          7) +
        1
    );
    return today;
  }
  console.log(
    nextDate(dayIndex).valueOf()
 );
  onHoldUntil =
    nextDate(dayIndex)
      .setHours(11 + 5, 30, 0, 0)
      .valueOf() / 1000;

  console.log(
    "Next Friday Pay date is : "
  );
  console.log(
    nextDate(dayIndex)
      .setHours(11 + 5, 30, 0, 0)
      .valueOf()
); //11 am + 5.30 for IST
//unix to date conversion
var date = new Date(onHoldUntil * 1000); // to datetime format so taht paycycle can be fetched and also pay date
console.log("date value is ", date);
payoutDate =  date.toISOString().substring(0,10) ;
console.log("Payout Date is : " , payoutDate);   

console.log(date);
payCycleStart = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() - 7).toISOString().slice(0,10);
payCycleEnd = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() - 1).toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Comment: your code actually produces 16th, 22nd and 29th - though, to be fair it doesn't output the first two at all - also note that `.toISOString` shows the date in UTC, not your local time, so that can throw things out by a day - which could throw things out by a week if you use it wrong